# Serialization Error: How do I create a UDF that consumes an ArrayType(StringType) column using a function that consumes java.util.List[String]?

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with schema:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Contents look like this

```
df.show(1)
+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[863e3434fffffff,...|
+---+--------------------+
```

I want add another column called "compacted" of type array[string] that will store the results of my function below, using a UDF.  The function accepts a Java List as input java.util.List[String], and outputs a Java List as well - but I have the function outputting to a Scala Array, like this:

```
def compactf(s: java.util.List[String])  = { H3.instance.compactAddress(s).asScala.toArray }
```

The function works just as I expect it to, returning a Scala Array.

```
compactf(my_test_java_list)
res48: Array[String] = Array(863e3434fffffff, 863e3435fffffff, 863e3092fffffff, 863e3090fffffff, 863e30ba7ffffff, 863e30bafffffff, 863e356b7ffffff, 863e356a7ffffff, 863e350d7ffffff, 863e350f7ffffff, 863e35c5fffffff, 863e35c57ffffff, 863e35d8fffffff, 863e35d9fffffff, 863e3436fffffff, 863e34347ffffff, 863e34357ffffff, 863e342afffffff, 863e3428fffffff, 863e30927ffffff, 863e30907ffffff, 863e3091fffffff, 863e308e7ffffff, 863e308efffffff, 863e30bb7ffffff, 863e30b87ffffff, 863e30b8fffffff, 863e30a77ffffff, 863e30a67ffffff, 863e35697ffffff, 863e35687ffffff, 863e356afffffff, 863e35757ffffff, 863e35777ffffff, 863e350dfffffff, 863e350c7ffffff, 863e350e7ffffff, 863e3511fffffff, 863e35117ffffff, 863e35c4fffffff)
```

However, when I try to incorporate it into a udf (below), it doesn't work.  For instance, this fails with a serialization error (Task not serializable):

```
val compact2udf = udf(compactf _)
df.withColumn("compacted", compact2udf(col("_2")))

df.withColumn("compacted", compact2udf(col("_2"))).show()
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

What I want is:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|           compacted|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|[863e3434fffffff,...|[863e3092fffffff,...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: What is inside `H3.instance.compactAddress`? does it use some not serializable classes?

Comment: if you look further down in the stacktrace, you should find a hint which field is not serializable

Comment: Thank you @grisha-weintraub and @raphael-roth. I'm using the [h3 library][https://github.com/uber/h3-java] (java binding) from uber.  The method I'm using (compactAddress) takes a java list of strings as input and returns a java list of strings as output.     If I look in the stacktrace, I see:   

```java.io.NotSerializableException: com.uber.h3core.H3Core
Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: com.uber.h3core.H3Core, value: com.uber.h3core.H3Core@68ce10f4)
 - field (class: H3$, name: instance, type: class com.uber.h3core.H3Core)
 - object (class H3$, H3$@6b1c1211)```